# JQuery Modify script

Tags: jquery

I currently have this script to work with a submit button, Can anyone help me modify this script to also work with links (a href)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('div.submitbutton').click(function(event) {
        $(this).val('Loading.. Please wait');
        $('#loading').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myform').submit();
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Add to the `selector` so that it also selects an anchor element and prevent the default action.

Comment: Please take the time to read the jQuery documentation, especially http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('div.submitbutton, a').click(function(event) {
    $(this).val('Loading.. Please wait');
    $('#loading').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myform').submit();
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add the `<a>` to your selector for the submit button e.g.

`$('div.submitbutton a').click(function.....`

Comment: Why do you think the links are inside the "buttons"?